# Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a 2008 R2 DC that has been replicated to a 2012 server.
When a user tries to logon a 2012 server connected to the replicated 2012 DC using Remote Desktop, he gets the following error message:

"Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in"

No problems RDP using the admin account though.
I might as well mention that that user is indeed a part of Domain Admins. Even after adding the user to "Administrators" group he still cant logon.

Could this be due to the fact that the 2012 DC Domain Functional Level is at 2008 R2 state?

Thanks,
X

Comment: what do you mean by this "2008 R2 DC that has been replicated to a 2012 server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the subnets to Sites and Services...
That fixed the problem.